# Why are my absolutely positioned elements in different places on depending on browser/devices?

Tags: css

I have about 6 divs that I set to position: absolute.
After reading other threads, I made sure the parent element was set to position: relative,
Still for some reason the vertical positioning of these elements differ depending on browser/device.

For example, the positioning looks okay on chrome for macbook.
But it is off on Safari for Macbook, Safari on iPad as well as Chrome and IE for Windows.

http://codepen.io/donnaloia/pen/WbYbLa

It is the suggestion divs (in light gray), that are not positioning correctly.

What am I doing wrong here?  Why is this happening?

```
.backgroundiv {
    background-image: url(/static/img/bg-hero.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 986px;
}
.background2div {
    background-color: black;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 800px;
    position: relative;
}
.linecontainer {
    width: 486px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 68px;
}
.formdiv {
    padding-top: 50px;
    float: center;
  background-color: white; 
  height: 845px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 632px;
  position: relative;
}
.selltitle {
    font-family: futura;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.forminput {
    float:right;
    margin-bottom: 32px;

}

.forminput input {
    padding-top: .5em;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
    width: 230px;
}
.forminput submit {
    padding-top: .5em;
}

.forminput2 {
  float:right;
  width: 232px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

textarea {
    padding: .5em;
    width: 221px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.checkmark1{
  top: 228px;
  display:none;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  left: 894px;
}
.checkmarkimg {
  width:20px;
}
.checkmark2{
  top:285px;
  display:none;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  left: 894px;
}
.checkmark3{
  top:462px;
  display:none;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  left: 894px;
}
.checkmark4{
  top:545px;
  display:none;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  left: 894px;
}

.checkmark5{
  top:603px;
  display:none;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  left: 894px;
}

input.parsley-success,
select.parsley-success,
textarea.parsley-success {
  color: #468847;
  background-color: #DFF0D8;
  border: 1px solid #D6E9C6;
}

input.parsley-error,
select.parsley-error,
textarea.parsley-error {
  color: #B94A48;
  background-color: #F2DEDE;
  border: 1px solid #EED3D7;
}

.inputholder.parsley-success.checkmarksuccess {
    display: block;
    width:26px;
    height:24px;
    position:absolute;
  }

.parsley-errors-list {
  margin: 2px 0 3px 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  line-height: 0.9em;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 6px;
  font-size:14px;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  -webkit-opacity: 0;

  transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.parsley-errors-list.filled {
  opacity: .5;
}

.suggest1{
  opacity: .45;
  margin-left:68px;
  position:absolute;
  top:153px;
  font-style: italic;

}
.suggest2{
  opacity: .45;
  margin-left:68px;
  width:150px;
  position:absolute;
  top:202px;
  font-style: italic;

}
.suggest3{
  opacity: .45;
  margin-left:68px;
  position:absolute;
  top:297px;
  font-style: italic;

}
.suggest4{
  opacity: .45;
  margin-left:68px;
  position:absolute;
  top:344px;
  font-style: italic;

}
.suggest5{
  opacity: .45;
  margin-left:68px;
  position:absolute;
  top:392px;
  width:132px;
  font-style: italic;

}

.suggest6{
  opacity: .45;
  margin-left:68px;
  position:absolute;
  top:440px;
  width:132px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.suggest7{
  color: red;
  opacity: .75;
  margin-left:325px;
  position:absolute;
  top:252px;
  width:132px;
  font-size:14px;
}

.suggest8{
  opacity: .45;
  margin-left:68px;
  position:absolute;
  top:489px;
  width:132px;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of absolute positioning for what you are trying to achieve. This definitely could easily be done without it. If you really want absolute positioning, shouldn't it be done relatively to your ``linecontainer`` elements instead?

Comment: That is so bad.  Don't use absolute positioning like that.  And you never specified a base font-size, but depend on `em` as a sizing unit is also bad.  My guess without ripping my hair out is that you are trying to mix px and em units, and without having specified a base font for the page, it's differing between browsers.

Comment: I see nothing on that page that should be absolutely positioned.  And you might want to start with using either reset.css or normalize.css for your page to help eliminate some of the browser differences (Selectable on codepen's css window).